# How do I encrypt an HTML field in a form, and then decrypt it on the server?

Tags: html, forms, encryption, ssl

Or better yet, is there a way I can enable SSL for just a form?

Due to some content on the page being from other sites, The page throws warnings about unencrypted data ( I think, it's been a while ). Otherwise, I'd just use SSL on the entire page and not worry about it.

Comment: Changing the entire page to SSL should not break your third party content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't encrypt the full page, you open yourself to Man In the Middle Attacks. Somebody can just impersonate your page, the user will enter his data in the wrong page and he will never notice, because he has no chance of checking the certificates.
You can do the POST request encrypted, but it offers a lower level of security